# npm install jquery fails

Tags: node.js, npm

Tried reading this stacktrace thoroughly but it didn't make me any smarter. Ideas?

```
sudo npm install jquery

npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3 <html><title>Request timeout</title><body><h1>Request timeout</h1></body></html>
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:147:21)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at Request.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:99:22)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:361:18)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at Request.emit (events.js:64:17)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:327:16)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1228:22)
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:303:27)
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
npm ERR! <html><title>Request timeout</title><body><h1>Request timeout</h1></body></html>
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:147:21)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:99:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:361:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:64:17)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:327:16)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1228:22)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:303:27)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jquery"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/fw/nodeprojects/cloudnode/zorro
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! arguments [ 'ILLEGAL' ]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fw/nodeprojects/cloudnode/zorro/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: Is this still happening? If so, try updating npm to latest. It looks like the error is because it's having issues pulling the package down. If the NPM guys changed their schema a bit between 1.0.106 and now it would explain it.

Comment: This stopped happening, without updating NPM that I believe was already the latest. However, I'm afraid I don't know the reason for it. It could've been because I uninstalled MacPorts ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. Looks like we have to use

> npm install jQuery

instead of

> npm install jquery

Thanks to [coolaj86](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues/17#issuecomment-2083588).

Comment: This then requires me to install jsdom (which lowercase jquery installs) but still fails.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I have the same problem as occasl. I am working on a mac. Could that be an npm problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the camel case jQuery is depreciated now

```
npm WARN deprecated jQuery@1.7.4: This is deprecated. Please use 'jquery' (all lowercase).
```

You got to use

```
npm install jquery
```

Comment: when I run tests with karma - it can't find jquery module with lowercase. It requires the uppercase one =/

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, I added 'sudo':

```
sudo npm install jquery
```

... that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To include jQuery in Node, first install with npm.

```
npm install jquery
```

For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```